# css border is not applied on table tr

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

This is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r323e/

it is very simple:

I want to put a border on the table tr so I tried this:

```
.table tr{
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #000000;
}
```

The `height` property is applied but the border is not.

why please? and how to fix it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your tr style.

```
.table tr{
display:block;
height: 30px;
border-bottom: 10px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: +1, it works I will accept your answer when the system allows

Comment: Beware that it'll break the table layout: all cells of a given column don't have an equal width anymore (except in OP fiddle where content of each row is identical, not a real case). And height instruction on a row is equivalent to min-height in general so it'd better to set `td {min-height:30px}`. Example : http://jsfiddle.net/r323e/1/

Answer (score 2):

you can define a tr class css like this

```
<tr class="border_bottom">
```

and in your css you can do this

```
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
```

tried in your code and works..good luck!!

Comment: +1 for your help but the other answer was better to me. many thanks

Comment: thanks my friend!! the objective is to help us giving many solutions...good luck!!!!